# Dynamically adding buttons to scroll view

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I would like some help with dynamically adding buttons to a `ScrollView`.  I've got it working with a `LinearLayout` but  obviously I can only add so many buttons before they no longer appear on screen.  My code is below with an attached image of its current state.

I tried changing every occurrence of `LinearLayout` with `ScrollView` in the code but when I ran it, I got an error that stated something along the lines of `ScrollViews can only have 1 direct child`.

I'm not sure how to make it work, so if someone could give me some guidance on how to do it, I would be very grateful.

My XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java Code (where I'm dynamically creating the buttons):

```
public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                final Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                btnTag.setText("" + (j + 1 + (i * 4)));
                btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
                row.addView(btnTag);
            }
            layout.addView(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Image of the current layout.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `ScrollView` can only have 1 child, and often it is the `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc.
You need to wrap your `LinearLayout` with a `ScrollView`, like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Or you can change your topmost `RelativeLayout` into `ScrollView` if it has only one child.

Comment: I'll have to try your first suggestion to wrap the `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`.  I can't change the top most `RelativeLayout` to `ScrollView` because I've got other things in there that I'm using the `RelativeLayout` to organize.  I didn't include it because I didn't think it was relevant (in hind sight it might've been useful just to know that they are there).  Anyways, for you first suggestion, do I need to change anything with the Java Code itself (i'm thinking just change every `LinearLayout` to `ScrollView` in code) or can I just wrap the `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView` in the XML?